# How to effectively track changes to items in Quote Calculator Plugin (QCP) in salesforce cpq?

Tags: cpq, quote, quotelineitem, cpq-plugins

I have a segmented product. On the product I want to avail a discount if a certain condition is met.

I've implemented this as

```
export function onAfterCalculate(quoteModel, quoteLineModels, conn) {
    setDiscount(quoteModel, quoteLineModels, conn);
    return Promise.resolve();
}

function setDiscount(quote, quoteLines, conn){
quoteLines.forEach(function(line){
    if(isSegmented(line)){
        var listUnitPrice = line.record['SBQQ__ListPrice__c'];
        var discount = (listUnitPrice * (5/100));
        line.record['extraDiscount'] = discount;
        line.record['SBQQ__ListPrice__c'] = listUnitPrice - discount;
    }
})
```

}

The problem with this approach is that every time I click on calculate, the whole process runs again and keeps on reducing the list price on each execution. This also happens when anything else on the quote line editor is modified.

What would be the recommended pattern to achieve this ?

Comment: I believe you're using the correct method here (onAfterCalculate). What if you add a custom checkbox field to the Quote Line that gets checked the first time the code runs and then prevents future runs if marked "true"?